# Drive mounted with flags different from /etc/fstab - not respecting suid, dev, or exec

Tags: mount, fstab, automounting

I have an `ext4` mounted with the flags `rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async` in `/etc/fstab` but running `mount` after mounting gives `rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user`.

How do I get it to mount exactly as written in `/etc/fstab` and (optionally) why is there such a difference?

I'm using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You must put the `exec`, `suid` and `dev` options after the `user` option, because `user` implies `noexec`, `nosuid` and `nodev`.

See [mount man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) for details:

> user
>
> Allow  an  ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  The name of the mounting user is written to the mtab file (or to the private libmount file in /run/mount on systems without a regular mtab)
> so that this same user can unmount the filesystem again.
>
> **This option implies the options noexec, nosuid, and  nodev  (unless  overridden  by  subsequent  options,  as  in  the  option  line user,exec,dev,suid)**